# AngularJS: Error: $q is not defined

Tags: angularjs, frontend, web-frontend

I want to make a promise in my angularjs controller. I took the example from the [Angularjs Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and pasted it in my controller. When I try to run the code, the console prints:

```
Error: $q is not defined
```

Why is this error happening and how do I solve it?

I tried to google this problem, but most questions revolve about more specific problems than mine.

A [(german) guide](https://angularjs.de/buecher/angularjs-buch/angularjs-promises) tells me that promises are already in angular js implemented and there is no need to add anything to it.

EDIT:

this is my controller:

```
app.controller("ArgumentationController", [
    '$scope', '$resource',
    function($scope, $resource) {
```

EDIT2:
A commentor suggested to inject $q. I did this:

```
app.controller("ArgumentationController", [
    '$scope', '$resource', '$q',
    function($scope, $resource, $q) {
```

Now, the error does not occur.

Comment: Did you inject $q in your controller?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your past code, no need of `$resource` in your code. Instead inject `$q` in it.
As you are creating a dummy promise using `$q`, make following changes.

```
 app.controller("ArgumentationController", [
        '$scope', '$q',
        function($scope, $q) {
```